# Content rotation not working in bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Haggler.asmx/GetFacebookFriends',
        //data: jsonText,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //'access_token':" + JSON.stringify(access_token) + "


        success: function (data) {
            var myObject = JSON.parse(eval('(' + data.d + ')'));
            var length = myObject.data.length;
            alert(length);

            //var container = document.getElementById('mfs');
            //var mfsForm = document.createElement('form');
            //mfsForm.id = 'mfsForm';

            // Iterate through the array of friends object and create a checkbox for each one.
            for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(myObject.data.length, 10) ; i++) {
                htmlT += '<a data-slide-index="' + i + '" href=""><img src="' + myObject.data[i].pic_square + '" /></a>';
                // var friendItem = document.createElement('div');


                pageIndex = 1;
                pageCount = 0;
                clearHtml = true;
                loadData(myObject.data[i].uid, function (html) { HtmlM += html; });
                // HtmlM += loadData(myObject.data[i].uid);





            }

            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'


            });

            $('#reload-slider').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                slider.reloadSlider({
                    mode: 'fade',
                    auto: true,
                    pause: 1000,
                    speed: 500
                });
            });

            //    alert(HtmlM);
            $('#bx-pager').html(htmlT);

            alert(HtmlM);
            $('.bxslider').html(HtmlM);




        },

        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="bxslider">

    </ul>

    <div id="bx-pager">

    </div>
```

I am generating bxslider content and the pager dynamically but bxslider doesn't work effectively when i do this. It gives me two li's simultaneously and not content one after the other.

[image]